# How to save font size and bg color to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I followed the answer from a similar question here on SO but now when I use the select box or colour picker to change the font size or back ground colour, nothing changes at all. I have commented the lines that I added in hopes to save the changes to the local storage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<header class="siteHeader">
            <div id="container">
                <select id="change_font_size">
                    <option value="225">225</option>
                    <option selected value="250">250</option>
                    <option value="300">300</option>
                    <option value="350">350</option>
                </select>
                <p style="float: left;">A+/-</p>
                <input type="color" id="colour_picker">
                <p style="float: right;">Background colour:</p>
                </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="burritos.html">BURRITOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var colour = localStorage.color || $('#colour_picker').val();
    //var size = localStorage.font_size || $('#change_font_size').val();

    //$('#color_picker').val(color);
    //$('#change_font_size').val(size);

    $("#change_font_size").change(function() {
        var font_size = $(this).val();
        //localStorage.font_size = font_size;
        $('.siteHeader').css("font-size", font_size + "%");
    });
    $('#colour_picker').change(function() {
        var background_colour = $(this).val();
        //localStorage.color = background_colour;
        $('.siteHeader').css("background-color", background_colour);
    });
});
```

Comment: you'd save it the same way you'd save anything else to local storage... so the question is really how are you accessing local storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage as shown below :

```
//Check if value exists or not
if (localStorage.getItem("font_size") === null) {
     localStorage.setItem("font_size", font_size);
} else {
     var font_size = localStorage.getItem("font_size");
}
```

You can store the value in localStorage by `setItem` and then retrieve the value by using `getItem`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this simpler solution:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
// SITE OPTIONS
var storage = window.localStorage;

// JUNK SIZE
function updateJunkSize(newSize) {
    storage.junkSize    = newSize;
}

// SET A DEFAULT
if (!storage.junkSize) {
    storage.junkSize = 4;
}
</script>
```

Working Example: play with the space junk options in real time at https://www.webveteran.com/about-this-site/site-options/
Your options get saved and are loaded when you come back.
[image]